# Asynchronous operations performance

Tags: .net, asynchronous, filestream

One of the features of [asynchronous programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(VS.85).aspx) in .NET is saving threads during long running operation execution. The `FileStream` class can be setup to allow asynchronous operations, that allows running (e.g.) a copy operation without virtually using any threads. To my surprise, I found that running asynchronous stream copy performs not only slower, but also uses more processing power than synchronous stream copy equivalent.

Is there any benchmark tests were done to compare a synchronous vs asynchronous operation execution (file, network, etc.)? Does it really make sense to perform an asynchronous operation instead of spanning separate thread and perform synchronous operation in server environment if the asynchronous operation is times slower than the synchronous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the conditions under which file i/o will be *actually* be asynchronous are rather specific, even at the native Win32 level. See [this article](http://www.lenholgate.com/archives/000765.html) for more details.

Comment: Just to clarify: That article says nothing about async vs sync I/O performance. All the tricks about increasing async performance are applicable to sync performance as well. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the article you included in your comment to @Alex's response.

> In situations where an I/O request is
>   expected to take a large amount of
>   time, such as a refresh or backup of a
>   large database or a slow
>   communications link, asynchronous I/O
>   is generally a good way to optimize
>   processing efficiency. However, for
>   relatively fast I/O operations, the
>   overhead of processing kernel I/O
>   requests and kernel signals may make
>   asynchronous I/O less beneficial,
>   particularly if many fast I/O
>   operations need to be made. In this
>   case, synchronous I/O would be better.
>   The mechanisms and implementation
>   details of how to accomplish these
>   tasks vary depending on the type of
>   device handle that is used and the
>   particular needs of the application.
>   In other words, there are usually
>   multiple ways to solve the problem.

FWIW, I think @Alex is correct that there is another thread running the kernel code associated with your I/O request.  That thread is not managed by your application, though.  The thread running the kernel code may itself block on an device I/O request and wait for the actual hardware to complete the request before signaling your user-mode thread, but it is still there nonetheless.

Using asynchronous threads shouldn't be thought of as a way to increase the speed of any particular request, but rather a way to increase the overall efficiency by allowing your application to continue processing on other tasks while awaiting relatively slow I/O.

Comment: Async I/O does not use threads on Windows NT. A storage driver may choose to use kernel worker threads however that would be very inefficient since threads are expensive in kernel mode.

Comment: I think it's really a matter of semantics. Whether you're using the kernel process or spawning a new kernel thread, there is still code running in kernel-mode on the calling thread's behalf to do the I/O operation.  You can't get away from some kernel code running to service the I/O operation.

Comment: That operation does not run in a separate thread. The storage devices are capable of performing I/O unattended and signal interrupts when they are done. That interrupt's "cleanup work" is done in one of existing threads without creating a new one.

Comment: I didn't say that it created a new thread.  I said it ran in a different thread than the user thread.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you benchmarked your copy operation correctly? Any asynchronous operation just create new thread and runs the operation in new thread while leaving main thread to do other things.

The asynchronous operations mostly give a a few simplifications(less lines of code) over creating the thread yourself but they should not impact performance more then creating a new Thread.

Comment: Pure asynchronous operations relay on hardware to invoke callbacks and they not spanning a new thread

Comment: What is "Pure asynchronous operation"? can you provide some links?

Comment: He means IO calls to hardware