# Why async performance in MVC worse then other approaches

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, model-view-controller

I know that I know nothing...
I  am investigating performance of different approaches of parraller programming.
And have some controversual results duting test. I want to clarify this things.
I have 3 approaches for simultaneous reading and processing several files.

1. classic **sequential** (assume simplest but worse performance)
2. classic **threads** (is not best for this task, because use
   I/O but not processor)
3. new **asyncronius**  (best for this task, beacause use I/O)

I run this test for 3 cases  100 times 5 concurent thread prolonged timeout 100s

```
ab -n 100 -c 5 -s 100
```

here results: min, avg and max

1. 3730   8653   14565 (best performance)
2. 5090   7627   13888
3. 12985  47973  71764 (worst performance)

How is it could be, the best method for this case shows worst results?

see below code it reads files from folder in the memory and just calculates it's total length this way.

1 sequential

```
        int directorySize = 0;string fileNames = "";
        foreach (var fileName in Directory.GetFiles(@"f:\Old\My Images\"))
        {
            StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(fileName);
            string res = sw.ReadToEnd();
            directorySize += res.Length;
            fileNames += fileName + "<br/>";
        }
        ViewData["Message"] = directorySize +" "+ fileNames;
```

2 threaded

```
int directorySize = 0;string fileNames = "";
        List<Task<string>> lst = new List<Task<string>>();
        foreach (var fileName in Directory.GetFiles(@"f:\Old\My Images\"))
        {
            lst.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{
                StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(fileName);
                return sw.ReadToEnd();
            }));
            fileNames += fileName + "<br/>";
        }

        while (lst.Count > 0)
        {
            var res = await Task.WhenAny(lst); lst.Remove(res);
            directorySize += res.Result.Length;
        }

        ViewData["Message"] = directorySize + " " + fileNames;
```

3 async

```
int directorySize = 0;string fileNames = "";
        List<Task<string>> lst = new List<Task<string>>();
        foreach (var fileName in Directory.GetFiles(@"f:\Old\My Images\"))
        {
            StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(fileName);
            lst.Add(sw.ReadToEndAsync());
            fileNames += fileName + "<br/>";
        }

        while(lst.Count>0)
        {
            var res = await Task.WhenAny(lst);lst.Remove(res);
            directorySize += (await res).Length;
        }

        ViewData["Message"] = directorySize + " " + fileNames;
```

Comment: Please fix your code to use using (streams) and await for all async operations (you missed one). You could also use ConfigureAwait(false) and then try again.

Comment: If you want to solve the particular problem of enumerating the directory and calculating the total size, then stop reading file contents only to [determine its size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length), use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` for the loop and a `StringBuilder` for `fileNames`. If you want to understand what is very wrong with your attempt at async/await in general, start at https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html.

Comment: for curious I fave made fix with var res= await sw.ReadToEndAsync(); but second loop removed because await returns result. Performence became worst as expected 16780 53374 72254

Comment: By awaiting a single task with `Task.WhenAny` you're sequentially awaiting the tasks which increases contention (if completed tasks are in the tail of the list while not-completed in the head you're just wasting time for waiting for in-progress tasks having some of them done). Apart of that it increases pressure on synchronization context - multiple task continuations without `ConfigureAwait(false)` are synchronized to be executed sequentially this again increases the contention. And one more aspect - 5 concurrent threads aren't enough - async is about scalability not performance itself.

Comment: Have changed to FileStream instead of stream reader but this class do not have readAsync with bufer result  so aproach is slightly diferent. results are 1) 284  826  3826  2) 257 2876  23396 3) 351  695 4423 seems async not worst